# Yet Another Java Service Wrapper (YAJSW): Network drive not found

Tags: networking, yajsw

I use YAJSW on a Windows Server 2012. It has some network drives that are used by my Java program. Starting the java program from console shows no problems but starting it through YAJSW clearly shows that the drive "R:" does not exist.

Is there any way to "tell" YAJSW about the network drives? These are standard mappings in our company and a variety of "path definition files" use them, so it would be hard work to rewrite my Java program to map all incoming paths to full network paths.

Answer (score 0):

A Service ist not aware of any "User-mapped" Network-shares.
U can mapp it in YAJSW, there is an example under scripts\mapNetworkDrive.gv.

Anyway it would be best to use a UNC path like "\\someserver\somefolder\..."

(\\\\someserver\\somefolder\\... in configfile)